# Polymer 2.0 - Can you write to fs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, fs, polymer-2.x

I'm working on an MVP for a project, and I'm trying to mock up a "database" quick and dirty. I thought for now I'll just put my "database" into a .json file and work with that. I am able to use `iron-ajax` to get a file read in to a Polymer property to be manipulated, however, I don't know how I could write it back onto the filesystem once I manipulated it. I tried

```
let fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('./db/db.json', json, 'utf8');
```

However, this does not work ([apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined), `require` does not work on the client side). I've tried googling around and checking the answers on the linked thread, but the answers are quite vague ("use `<script>` tag" - okay, but how?) and I haven't been able to figure it out. How would I be able to pass a json object and write it back to the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no you can't. You have to write a little backend for that but for that i usually use the localStorage there you can store JSON and read write.